# AX 2012 Display totals in a form part on a list page

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

How can you display the total quantity of all selected records from a list page on a form part?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty open ended, but here is some sample code I wrote to loop over the selected records so you can "do" something with it.  I just chose `SalesLine` as a sample table buffer that you might select.

```
int                 i;
Qty                 totalQty;

// Make this your data source
FormDataSource      fds; 

// This is an array of what records are marked
Array               markedRecords = fds.recordsMarked();

// This is the table buffer that you can look at
// when looping over the selected records
SalesLine           salesLine;

// This loops over the selected records so you can "do" something
i = 1;
while (i <= markedRecords.lastIndex())
{
    salesLine = fds.cursor(markedRecords.value(i));

    totalQty += salesLine.SalesQty;

    i++;
}
```